# Hive Calculation of Percentage

Tags: command, hive, percentage

I am trying to write a simple code to calculate the percentage of occurrence of distinct instances in a table.
Can I do this in one go???

Below is my code which is giving me error.

```
select 100 * total_sum/sum(total_sum) from jav_test;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the past when I have had to do similar things this is the approach I've taken:

```
SELECT
  jav_test.total_sum AS total_sum,
  withsum.total_sum AS sum_of_all_total_sum,
  100 * (jav_test.total_sum / withsum.total_sum) AS percentage
FROM
  jav_test,
  (SELECT sum(total_sum) AS total_sum FROM jav_test) withsum    -- This computes sum(total_sum) here as a single-row single-column table aliased as "withsum"
;
```

The presence of the `total_sum` and `sum_of_all_total_sum` columns in the output is just to convince myself that the correct math took place - the one you are interested in is `percentage`, based on the query you posted in the question.

After populating a small dummy table, this was the result:

```
hive> describe jav_test;
OK
total_sum                   int                                 
Time taken: 1.777 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select * from jav_test;
OK
28
28
90113
90113
323694
323694
Time taken: 0.797 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
hive> SELECT
    >   jav_test.total_sum AS total_sum,
    >   withsum.total_sum AS sum_of_all_total_sum,
    >   100 * (jav_test.total_sum / withsum.total_sum) AS percentage
    > FROM jav_test, (SELECT sum(total_sum) AS total_sum FROM jav_test) withsum;
...
... lots of mapreduce-related spam here
...
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 3 seconds 370 msec
OK  
28  827670  0.003382990805514275
28  827670  0.003382990805514275
90113       827670  10.887551802046708
90113       827670  10.887551802046708
323694      827670  39.10906520714777
323694      827670  39.10906520714777
Time taken: 41.257 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
hive>
```

Comment: thanks rchang for your reply, I have tried this but still getting the same error. 
total_sum in my code refers to a column with some values and sum(total_sum) gives a single value.
however when I run the command it generates error

Comment: @Javad What is the error you are receiving?  I was able to run the query with a dummy table (only half a dozen rows or so).

Comment: FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 2:2 Expression not in GROUP BY key jav_test

Comment: @Javad Please check your query for typos against what I've posted in the answer.  The only aggregation function being used in a `SELECT` statement should be the `sum` function inside the subquery that is generating the `withsum` table, and it is the ONLY thing being selected, so there should not be a `GROUP BY` issue.

Comment: SELECT
    >   jav_test.total_sum AS total_sum,
    >   withsum.total_sum AS sum_of_all_total_sum,
    >   100 * (jav_test.total_sum / withsum.total_sum) AS percentage
    > FROM jk_test, (SELECT sum(total_sum) AS total_sum FROM jav_test) withsum;
FAILED: Parse Error: line 5:28 mismatched input ',' expecting EOF near 'jk_test

Comment: thank, I have tried and here is the command with the output i am getting

Comment: @Javad It looks like you've mis-spelled `jav_test` (the error you posted indicates you typed `jk_test` instead).  I'll post the full dump from my Hive session shortly and update the answer with it.

Comment: have you created a separate table withsum in a different command??
where is it calculating the sum(total_sum)?

Comment: could you please put a small comment next to the lines as it seems the hive i am using does not support everything

Comment: @Javad I've annotated the original answer to make it clear where `sum(total_sum)` gets computed (and stored as an ephemeral table named `withsum` in the context of this query).